# call two function one after another in javascript settimeout

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

I need to run following code

```
document.getElementById("someID").focus();
```

after below code

```
setTimeout(function(){loadEditor(param);}, 50);
```

But i am unable to make it asynchronous.Since I can not modify

```
function loadEditor(param){ /* some stuff */  }
```

Is there anyway out to do this?
What I have tried till now

```
setTimeout(function(){
    loadEditor(param);
    document.getElementById("someID").focus();
}, 50);
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.when( loadEditor('question_stem-text') ).done(function() {
        document.getElementById("someID").focus();
        });
}, 50);
```

Not successful

Comment: What does `loadEditor` do?

Comment: It is initializing lots of values and loading editor for fields

Comment: In your first attempt. Have you tried `console.log()` to check if it gets called?

Comment: yes its getting called

Comment: Check if `loadEditor` implements a callback call after it's done (I believe it's async, so it should in theory). Otherwise you should edit `loadEditor` and add a callback call when it's done.

Answer (score 2):

```
//ES6++
const delay = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () = > {
        loadEditor(param);
        resolve();
    }, 50);
});

delay.then( () => {
    document.getElementById("someID").focus();
});
```